# Tried to execute the incremental import sqoop job, but there are the following errors

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, sqoop, incremental-build

Tried to execute the incremental import job using sqoop, but I'm getting errors as shown below. I have also put the code I'm using to do the same. The tables are in rdbms, I'm trying to increment import it into hdfs. The job is created successfully only it's throwing errors while executing it. Management server is working just fien. I checked with the login credentials, I restarted the Management server and ran the sqoop job, still the error stayed.
I set up hadoop on pseudo distribution mode, localhost.

```
sqoop job --create <jobname> -- import \
--connect "jdbc:sqlserver://<servername>;database=<databasename>" \
--username "<username>" \
--password "<password>" \
--driver com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver \
--table "<tablename>" \
--append \
--check-column "<columnname>" \
--last-value < > \
--incremental lastmodified \
--fields-terminated-by <> \
--target-dir <path> \
-m 1


ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user '<username>'. ClientConnectionId:<clientconnectionid>
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user '<username>'. ClientConnectionId:<clientconnectionid>
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:254)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:84)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:2964)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:2244)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$000(SQLServerConnection.java:43)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:2230)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1717)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1328)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:993)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:829)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1012)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.makeConnection(SqlManager.java:885)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager.getConnection(GenericJdbcManager.java:52)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:744)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:767)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnInfoForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:270)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypesForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:241)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypes(SqlManager.java:227)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.ConnManager.getColumnTypes(ConnManager.java:295)
    at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.getColumnTypes(ClassWriter.java:1833)
    at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generate(ClassWriter.java:1645)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:107)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:478)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:605)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.JobTool.execJob(JobTool.java:228)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.JobTool.run(JobTool.java:283)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)
18/01/11 15:07:32 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.IOException: No columns to generate for ClassWriter
    at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generate(ClassWriter.java:1651)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:107)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:478)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:605)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.JobTool.execJob(JobTool.java:228)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.JobTool.run(JobTool.java:283)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CL stack clearly says that the username you are trying to use in sqoop command to comment to the sql server doesn’t have access. Check with the sql admin to see if you have proper rights or not.

Comment: I checked with the username/password, I have proper rights as well. That was the first thing I checked.
Thank you.

Comment: I could clear the error thank you. I had put <schema>.<tablename>, I removed the schema name and everything worked just fine.